# Cant escape get and use it in query

Tags: php, mysqli, pagination

I'm using a get parameter in my current pagination, and it's working fine. However, today I came across the idea of SQL injections, and therefore I tried to mysqli_real_escape_string it. When I refreshed the page, it seemed to have problems with using fetch_array on a query that uses that get parameter.

Error I get:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 106
```

Line 106:

```
while($fetchlistquery = $Listquery->fetch_array()) {
```

Entire code snippet:

```
// Prepare pagination
    $getPage = $LibraryUser->mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET["page"]); 
    if(isset($getPage)) { $page  = $getPage; } else { $page = 1; }; 
    $start_from = ($page-1) * 5; 

// Get articles
    $Listquery = $LibraryArticle->mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM site_articles ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start_from, 5");
    while($fetchlistquery = $Listquery->fetch_array()) {
```

Update:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-5, 5' at line 1
```

This only occours when you're not in an actual page like ?page=1 or ?page=2.

Any idea how to make it working?

Comment: Have a look at [mysqli_error](http://php.net/mysqli_error) and see what error you're getting from the `query` call.

Comment: Try `var_dump($LibraryArticle->mysqli->error)`

Comment: @JonStirling You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-5, 5' at line 1 - which is kinda weird because I get no errors if I don't escape the GET...

Comment: Sounds like `$page` is getting set to 0 (or falsey).

Comment: @JonStirling Updated my post. It's only page 1 that gets that error, page 2 and forwards works fine...

Comment: Basically you need to validate `$page` and make sure it's never less than 1.

Comment: @JonStirling which is what I do already: if(isset($getPage)) { $page  = $getPage; } else { $page = 1; };

Comment: No you don't. All that does is check that $getPage is set and not null. It doesn't care beyond that. So if $getPage = -1 then page = -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to check the `$page` value before performing query. And avoid using *, use proper column names.

```
if ($start_from >= 0)
    $query = "SELECT * FROM site_articles ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start_from, 5";
else
    $query = "SELECT * FROM site_articles ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 5";

// Get articles
    $Listquery = $LibraryArticle->mysqli->query($query);
    while($fetchlistquery = $Listquery->fetch_array()) {
```

Comment: validate `$start_from`

Comment: Ah, I validated $start_from and set it to 0 if it was below 0! Thanks!

Comment: if `$_GET['page']'=0 then `$start_page' is `(0-1)*5 = -5`. if `$_GET['page']'=1 this is `$start_page = (1-1)*5 = 0` . if `$_GET['page']'=2 then `$start_page = (2-1)*5 = 5` if you are not getting value according to above equation then try to `var_dump` values at different level.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `isset()` function in a wrong place. You should check if `$_GET['page']` is set or not first.
`$LibraryUser->mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET["page"])` returns `""` when there is no `$_GET['page']`, which is then set as value for `$getPage`. So your `isset($getPage)` is always `TRUE`, which makes the main problem. Fix it first and it will work.

```
if(isset($_GET["page"])) {
   $getPage = $LibraryUser->mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET["page"]); 
} else {
   $getPage = 1;
}
$page =  $getPage;
```